# '1 new item in your Stack Exchange inbox' email doesn't have a working logo for Area51!

Tags: bug, area-51, email, logo

> [image]

You can see the alt text is shown instead of the image^^.

The image points to http://area51.stackexchange.com/img/apple-touch-icon.png and that is Page Not Found.

I can't find the actual URL...

The `<img>`:

```
<img src="https://ci4.googleusercontent.com/proxy/rTOuR7U5y_NG8Vc7ok1XZvHOX4Ttaga6Qb9c5l5yPu2Z5iDrQpK3H1mJzKvyT-VZr-mbxqKHt3yDZ7o2Lgxi_FTkuRPU2tBwpWxH0hFr=s0-d-e1-ft#http://area51.stackexchange.com/img/apple-touch-icon.png" alt="Area 51" width="48" height="48" style="min-height:48px;width:48px" class="CToWUd">
```

Gmail caches all image sent, so the 'googleusercontent' is that - you can see the *real* URL at the end of the source (which is what I've written above)

Comment: are you on mobile website or iOS app?

Comment: @Hack on my computer, it's the email you get for unread massages

Comment: Can you do a 'Page view source' and show how the raw html code looks for this line.

Comment: @HackerKarma the URL I've shown in the question is what the raw html code says.

Comment: Could you please add that to your post? not just URL but the entire <img ....> HTML element. I would like to add the same to my answer for the comparison.

Comment: Thanks, Updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

This is definitely a URL issue.

The correct URL of the Area51 'apple-touch-icon.png' should be:

```
https://cdn.sstatic.net/area51/img/apple-touch-icon.png
```

[image: Area 51]

and this is how it looks when you scale the width and height of the image: (`width="48" height="48" style="min-height:48px;width:48px"`)

[image]

Here is an excerpt from Google's [Official Gmail Blog](http://gmailblog.blogspot.com/2013/12/images-now-showing.html): (emphasis mine)

> But thanks to new improvements in how Gmail handles images, you’ll
>   soon see all images displayed in your messages automatically across
>   desktop, iOS and Android. Instead of serving images directly from
>   their original external host servers, **Gmail will now serve all images
>   through Google’s own secure proxy servers**

Embedded images will now be saved by Google, and the e-mail content will be modified to display those images from Google’s *cache*, instead of from a third-party server.

As per the OP's raw HTML source code:

`<img src="https://ci4.googleusercontent.com/proxy/rTOuR7U5y_NG8Vc7ok1XZvHOX4Ttaga6Qb9c5l5yPu2Z5iDrQpK3H1mJzKvyT-VZr-mbxqKHt3yDZ7o2Lgxi_FTkuRPU2tBwpWxH0hFr=s0-d-e1-ft#http://area51.stackexchange.com/img/apple-touch-icon.png" alt="Area 51" width="48" height="48" style="min-height:48px;width:48px" class="CToWUd">`

You can see Google's proxy server is ***caching*** image from: `http://area51.stackexchange.com/img/apple-touch-icon.png`

Whereas, the correct URL of Area51 icon image is:

```
https://cdn.sstatic.net/area51/img/apple-touch-icon.png
```

Google's proxy server only caches/proxies image used in the SE's e-mail i.e. currently pointed to `http://area51.stackexchange.com/img/apple-touch-icon.png`. So, the URL for the image in the e-mail is *wrong* as specified image does *not* exist at that address.

P.S.

I am not sure when was the image from `area51.stackexchange.com/img/apple-touch-icon.png` was moved to the current CDN location i.e. `cdn.sstatic.net/area51/img/apple-touch-icon.png'. I guessed the image location from the post "[How does Stack Overflow make it so their apple-touch-icon doesn't have a border effect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28039932/how-does-stack-overflow-make-it-so-their-apple-touch-icon-doesnt-have-a-border)". All I did was replaced the 'stackoverflow' with 'area51' in the URL path.

Comment: Google's proxy only proxies the image SE uses in the email - so the URL for the image in the email is wrong, your URL might be the correct one, in which case it shouldn't be too hard to fix; it should just be a matter of changing the URL.